# Adding the DragDropContext gives me an error about exporting the ES6 module

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

So I started to integrate the react dnd library into my application, and the first thing I tried to do is add the DragDropContext with the Html5 backend.

When I add the attribute to the class I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Expected the backend to be a function or an ES6 module
>   exporting a default function.

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)
class UserHowView extends React.Component {
  ...
  ..
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 ...
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(userShowView);
```

What am I doing wrong so far?

One of the examples for the library has this:

```
@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)
export default class Container extends Component {
```

But my definition and export are separate.

Answer (score 1):

This library has a breaking change since v11.0.0 [breaking changes](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/releases/tag/v11.0.0):

> from
> `import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend`
> to
> `import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend`

If you are still encountering the issue, please check this [issue in repo](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/973#issuecomment-384956171)
and make sure you're not including `DragDropContext` in your render function

Answer (score 0):

Remove the braces from the HTML5Backend import statement. Replace with the following:

```
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
```

This has resolved the issue for me.